# magento 2 customer Exception message: Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: magento2, php, debug

Admin side on save customer getting following exception:
Please help

system exception:

```
[2017-09-06 11:28:49] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 2934
Trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(2934): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Array to string...', 'C:\\wamp\\www\\app...', 2934, Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource.php(168): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->prepareColumnValue(Array, Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb.php(728): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource->_prepareDataForTable(Object(Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Seller), 'pg_marketplace_...')
#3 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb.php(784): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->prepareDataForUpdate(Object(Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Seller))
#4 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb.php(403): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->updateObject(Object(Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Seller))
#5 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Model\AbstractModel.php(631): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save(Object(Webkul\Marketplace\Model\Seller))
#6 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\app\code\Webkul\Marketplace\Observer\AdminhtmlCustomerSaveAfterObserver.php(205): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
#7 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault.php(73): Webkul\Marketplace\Observer\AdminhtmlCustomerSaveAfterObserver->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#8 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Webkul\Marketplace\Observer\AdminhtmlCustomerSaveAfterObserver), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#9 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Event\Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#10 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\var\generation\Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('adminhtml_custo...', Array)
#11 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\module-customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save.php(267): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('adminhtml_custo...', Array)
#12 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\var\generation\Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save->execute()
#13 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php(102): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor->execute()
#14 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#18 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#21 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\module-backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\var\generation\Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#24 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(55): Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#27 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#28 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#31 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#33 C:\wamp\www\app_saturday\index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#34 {main} [] []
[2017-09-06 11:28:52] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header' tries to reorder itself towards 'global.notices', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2017-09-06 11:28:52] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'notifications', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2017-09-06 11:28:52] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'notification.messages', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
```

Admin observer COde

https://codeshare.io/5w4M39

Added code to get the array .
print "

```
";
print_r($postData);
exit;
```

`Array
(
[customer] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 10
        [website_id] => 1
        [email] => albasitstore@pocketgrocery.com
        [group_id] => 1
        [store_id] => 1
        [created_at] => 2017-04-22 10:00:52
        [updated_at] => 2017-09-06 14:02:46
        [is_active] => 1
        [disable_auto_group_change] => 0
        [created_in] => Default Store View
        [prefix] => 
        [firstname] => Al Basit
        [middlename] => 
        [lastname] => Store
        [suffix] => 
        [dob] => 
        [rp_token_created_at] => 2017-04-22 10:00:52
        [taxvat] => 
        [failures_num] => 0
        [sendemail_store_id] => 1
    )

[address] => Array
    (
        [7] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 7
                [parent_id] => 10
                [created_at] => 2017-06-06 09:37:27
                [updated_at] => 2017-09-06 14:02:48
                [is_active] => 1
                [city] => lahore
                [company] => abc
                [country_id] => PK
                [firstname] => test
                [lastname] => test
                [middlename] => 
                [postcode] => 54000
                [prefix] => 
                [region] => 
                [region_id] => 
                [street] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => nothing
                        [1] => nothig
                    )

                [suffix] => 
                [telephone] => 03331234567
                [vat_id] => 
                [customer_id] => 10
                [default_billing] => false
                [default_shipping] => false
            )

    )

[twitter_id] => 
[tw_active] => 0
[facebook_id] => 
[fb_active] => 0
[instagram_id] => 
[instagram_active] => 0
[gplus_id] => 
[gplus_active] => 0
[youtube_id] => 
[youtube_active] => 0
[vimeo_id] => 
[vimeo_active] => 0
[pinterest_id] => 
[pinterest_active] => 0
[moleskine_id] => 
[moleskine_active] => 0
[contact_number] => 
[shop_title] => 
[company_locality] => 
[country_pic] => PK
[company_description] => dsaf
[return_policy] => dsaf
[shipping_policy] => fsd
[meta_keyword] => 
[meta_description] => sadf
[banner_pic] => 
[logo_pic] => 
[form_key] => fy8hLln8xn5JU5xo
[commission] => 10.0000
)`

Comment: There is something going wrong in the following observer `Webkul\Marketplace\Observer\AdminhtmlCustomerSaveAfterObserver`.

Comment: Would you like to help me than? I am not experienced in magento

Comment: @Mr.Lewis updated adminobservercode as well.

Comment: also I have made no changes in any core file but why it is showing such issue

Comment: @DanielButt could you please try to comment `$value->addData($postData);` out on line 203 and if you now can save the customer please check data in the array `$postData` because there is an array in here which is transformed to string.

Comment: @Mr.Lewis Updated question and pasted the array as you requested.